# React useSelector not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a selectors folder with the selector.js file

```
const isRecipeFavorited = state => recipeId => {
    const recipe = state.find(recipe => recipe.id === recipeId)
    console.log(`Selector isRecipeFavourtied: ${recipeId}`)
    return recipe ? recipe.is_fav : false
}
```

This is my favicon.js file which calls this useSelector.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { View, TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import {isRecipeFavorited} from '../selectors/selectors'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { favids } from '../reducers/favids'

const FavIcon = ({recipeid, onToggle, isFavourite, text}) => {
 
  const isFavNew = useSelector(isRecipeFavorited(recipeid))

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.favItem} onPress={() => onToggle(recipeid)}>
        <FontAwesome name={isFavNew === true ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'} size={40} color='red' />
        <Text> {text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default FavIcon
```

I keep getting an error saying my selector is not a function. _selectors.isRecipeFavourited is not a function.
I am trying to retrieve the value of the recipe.is_fav from the state.
I am also using Redux in this project.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to reverse `state` and `recipeId` in your selector function, i.e.:

```js
const isRecipeFavorited = recipeId => state => {...}
```

This is a valid [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector):

```js
const thing = useSelector(state => state.thing);
```

In your case, you're calling a function with another type of argument, which in turn should return a function of the type that `useSelector` is expecting.

Comment: i've tired reversing as you've advised but still the same error

Comment: @abe I've changed the useSelector to try and figure out what is causing the issue, apparently the state.find or if i change it to state.map causes the issue. tried logging the state see output of logging the state. `{"favids":[{"recipeid":1234,"is_fav":true},{"recipeid":231432,"is_fav":true}]}` I keep getting the error state.map & state.find is undefined. Any ideas ?

Comment: If that is your state then it’s not an array.  Looks like you want state.favids.find().

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by drilling down into the favids object.

The selector function has been modified as below.

````
    const recipe = state.favids.find(recipe => recipe.recipeid === recipeId)
    return recipe ? recipe.is_fav : false
}```
````